# (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '0.0.0.0' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")

Tags: mysql, docker, sqlalchemy

I try to connect flask sqlalchemy container with mysql container. And configurate connection between them.
I have init_db python while which create all tables in my project:

```
from model import Base

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://test:test@0.0.0.0/test')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

And my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  flask:
    build: ./flask
    container_name: flask
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./flask:/flask
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 5000:5000

  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql_db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_USER=test
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3308:3308
```

When I've tried to save data in my with sqlalchemy I received error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '0.0.0.0' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

I've tried to add sql file for my db but it couldn't help. And when i open db container test db doesn't exist.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not a valid target address. Do you mean `127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this docker-compose environment, the `flask` container can reach the `db` container at dns `db` but not `0.0.0.0`.

Therefore, you will have to update your code to be like this

```
from model import Base

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://test:test@db/test')

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```